# Why does csvWriter require a StreamWriter object, why can't it make it for me?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, file, oop

In the following example, why do I need to make a SEPERATE `StreamWriter` class and then pass it to the `CsvWriter`?

It just feels repetitive and redundant. What if I never need to use the `StreamWriter` again? And secondly, if I need a `StreamWriter`every time I want to use `CsvWriter`, wouldn't it be better for the `CsvWriter` to handle that for me?

```cs
var writer = new StreamWriter("./Output.csv"))
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(songQueryResults);
}
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Lately I've been learning OOP and this seems to go against the idea of encapsulation which is why I'm asking this question

Comment: `CsvWriter` can stream its output to anywhere. Files, Network, Memory, maybe even the moon. If it would just take in a file name and create the stream itself, all of this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: This is typical Dependency Injection design. Side point: `writer` needs a `using` to dispose it

Comment: What is CsvWriter? Is this a library that you're using? Why haven't you tagged it? If it's a third party library, why haven't you asked the question to the maintainers? Why are you asking us here on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.  It can be any `TextWriter`.  That means, sure, `StreamWriter`.  And also `HttpWriter` or anything else you might think of for an odd use case in the future where you need to write a CSV and might write your own class to handle.  (Maybe `TcpWriter`?  `DBWriter`?)

`CsvWriter`'s one job is to format CSV output.  It doesn't care where it's going, so it depends on a `TextWriter` to persist it somewhere.  That's proper encapsulation.

Comment: that makes alot of sense. interesting how the csvwriter can work so scalably and with different output streams